# Learn You a Haskell For Great Good "Syntax in Functions" Error

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, and am following the tutorial given in:

http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions

The tutorial gives the following example:

```
lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String  
lucky 7 = "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"  
lucky x = "Sorry, you're out of luck, pal!"
```

However, I have my GHCI open and when I type the first line, I get the following error:

```
<interactive>:231:1: Not in scope: `lucky'
```

So I am having trouble following this chapter.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't write top-level definitions directly into GHCi like that. You need to write them into a file and then load that file into GHCi either by passing the filename as an argument (i.e. `ghci Bla.hs`) or by loading it from within GHCi using `:load Bla.hs`.

From within GHCi you can only use local definitions using `let` like you would in a `do` block.

Comment: Thanks, this feels much better than trying to make GHCi do things it isn't meant for.  I installed Sublime Text, put the code in there, pressed Ctrl-Shift-B, and am finally able to start doing real Haskell coding.

Answer (score 13):

When typing it into GHCi, you can do this with a `let` statement and a few semicolons or by wrapping it in `:{` and `:}`, as such

```
> let lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String; lucky 7 = "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"; lucky x = "Sorry, you're out of luck, pal!"
```

Or

```
> :{
| let lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String
|     lucky 7 = "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"
|     lucky x = "Sorry, you're out of luck, pal!"
| :}
```

You can also use the `+m` flag to make multi-line input the default:

```
> :set +m
> let lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String
|     lucky 7 = "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"
|     lucky x = "Sorry, you're out of luck, pal!"
|
> mapM_ (putStrLn . lucky) [1..10]
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a little unwieldy to try and add multiline definitions from GHCi.

There are a couple of workflows to consider. First is to create a new file using your favorite text editor ( `Foo.hs` ). Load it in the GHCi and then cycle back and forth between your `$EDITOR` and the repl using the GHCi command `:edit`.

Equivalently just create a separate file, launch GHCi and load it using `:load` and `:reload` as you make changes.

Answer (score 3):

LYAH is a bit unclear in this regard, but you can't really do that. This is really a greater symptom of a big difference between GHCi and other repls, like say the one you get by running `python`. The syntax in GHCi is a *little* bit different that the syntax for writing code in files, so you can't just paste chunks of code from files and expect them to work. This snippet is an example.

The first line: `lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String` is giving `lucky` a type signature - that's what the `::` operator does. When you type that line into GHCi it looks for a symbol `lucky` and can't find one. Assigning explicit types to functions in GHCi is kind of a pain, so the write-to-a-file-then-load workflow as described in the other answers is probably your best bet.